# Objeto como parámetro del constructor de una clase

Tags: java

He creado la clase vértice

```
public class Vertice {

    private float x;
    private float y;

    public Vertice(float _x, float _y){
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
}
```

y también la clase Linea que tiene dos vértices como variables

```
public class Linea {

    private Vertice Inicio;
    private Vertice Fin;

    public Linea(Vertice _Inicio, Vertice _Fin){
        Inicio = new Vertice(_Inicio.xVertice(), _Inicio.yVertice());
        Fin = new Vertice(_Fin.xVertice(), _Fin.yVertice());
    }
}
```

y quisiera en el main inicializar la clase linea así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Linea L = new Linea((Vertice)(1.0f, 0.0f), (Vertice)(2.0f, 1.0f));

}
```

envés que tener que crear dos variables de tipo vértice
¿se puede hacer algo así?

pregunto porque al recrear lo mismo en c++ no me da problemas
el código en c++:

clase vértice

```
class Vertice{
private:
float x, y;
public:
Vertice();
Vertice(float _x, float _y);
};
```

clase linea

```
class Linea{
private:
Vertice Inicio, Fin;
public:
Linea(Vertice _Inicio, Vertice _Fin);
};
```

constructor de vértice

```
Vertice::Vertice(float _x, float _y){
x = _x;
y = _y;
}

Vertice::Vertice(){
x = 0.0f;
y = 0.0f;
}
```

constructor de linea

```
Linea::Linea(Vertice _Inicio, Vertice _Fin){
Inicio = _Inicio;
Fin = _Fin;
}
```

creo el objeto linea

```
int main(){
Linea L(Vertice(4.0f, 5.0f), Vertice(7.0f, 8.0f));
return 0;
}
```

no me da errores el código en c++

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Ya me confundí usas la etiqueta Java pero ahora mencionas C++

Comment: solo recree lo mismo en c++ y si funciona como c++ y java se parecen pensé que se podría hacer por eso pregunto

Answer (score 1):

C++ y Java son dos lenguajes diferentes, por lo que al compararlos deberías ser especialmente cauto.

La llamada que deberías hacer para que funcione en Java sería la siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Linea linea = new Linea(new Vertice(1.0f, 0.0f), new Vertice(2.0f, 1.0f));
}
```

Y ahora te explico por qué.

En C++, cuando declaras una variable de una clase, y esta variable no es un puntero, se llama al constructor por defecto para construir un objeto de la clase.

```
Vertice v;    // Se llama al constructor por defecto de la clase Vertice
```

Si quieres declarar variables sin memoria dinámica, y llamar a otro constructor puedes hacerlo utilizando paréntesis o llaves.

```
Vertice v2(3, 5);    // Se llama al constructor con dos parámetros
Vertice v3{4, 5};    // Equivalente a la sentencia anterior
```

Incluso puedes llamar de manera explícita al constructor por defecto, este solo mediante llaves.

```
Vertice vx();    // Error: parece la definición de una función
Vertice v4{};    // Correcto: se llama al constructor por defecto
```

Ahora bien, cuando declaras un puntero a un objeto de una clase, no se llama a ningún constructor, lo tienes que crear explícitamente mediante el operador `new`.

```
Vertice *vd;    // Se define un puntero a Vertice, no se crea ningún objeto
vd = new Vertice();    // Creamos un Vertice en memoria dinámica
```

En el último caso, la memoria reservada con `new` tendremos que liberarla con `delete`.

Ahora bien, como mencionaba, Java es un lenguaje totalmente distinto.

Para tu caso, tienes que tener en cuenta que todo objeto de una clase cualquiera has de crearlo con `new`. Aquí no se va a llamar a ningún constructor si no haces un `new`.

Cabe destacar que esto es porque en Java, cuando creas un objeto, se le asigna un identificador único, el Object Identifier, y las variables solo guardan el OID del objeto. Mientras no se cree el objeto, una variable no asignada, contendrá el valor de OID `null`, que indica que esa variable no está apuntando a ningún objeto.

```
Vartice v;    // Declaramos la variable v, que inicialmente contiene null
v = new Vertice();    // Llamamos al constructor, v contiene el OID del objeto creado
```

Un último apunte: las variables de tu programa, así como los atributos definidos en una clase, comienzan siempre por minúscula.
Por esto, he puesto `Linea linea` en vez de `Linea L`. En todo caso puedes poner `Linea l`, en minúscula.

Answer (score 0):

A la hora de definir el constructor de linea no te convendría hacerlo así?

```
 public Linea(float inicioX, float inicioY, float finX, float finY){
    Inicio = new Vertice(inicioX, inicioY);
    Fin = new Vertice(finX, finY);
}
```

Ya que no le veo sentido pasarle por parámetro un objeto del tipo vértice para solo usar sus datos.
En el main te quedaria:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Linea L = new Linea(1.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione con la sentencia new:

```
Linea L = new Linea(new Vertice(5, 2), new Vertice(1, 3));
```

no me da errores